# SQL Server OR operator causing massive loop join

Tags: sql-server, performance, join, optimization, exists, query-performance

The query below is very slow (running over a minute) and I have narrowed down the issue to the `OR` operator (`...OR (EXISTS (SELECT...`).

I used live execution to verify that there is a nested loop join between the tables for the OR statement and then records are joined back to the `EmailTable` in the execution plan.

Basically, `EmailTable` is being probed twice.

If I add a hint `OPTION (MERGE JOIN)`, the query is finishing within a second.

Please show me how to re-write this query so that the optimizer chooses a better plan by default.

`EmailTable` and `TeamMembers` has clustered index on `INS_ID`. Statistics on the tables are updated often.

```
DECLARE @a INT
    ,@b BIT
    ,@c INT
    ,@d INT
    ,@e INT;

SELECT [XYZ].[CNT] AS [C]
FROM (
    SELECT COUNT(1) AS [CNT]
    FROM [dbo].[EmailTable] AS [table1]
    WHERE ([table1].[INS_ID] = @a)
        AND ([table1].[ACTIVE] = 1)
        AND ([table1].[QUEUED_TO_SEND] = @b)
        AND ([table1].[OWNER_USER_ID] <> @c)
        AND (
            ([table1].[OWNER_USER_ID] IN (- 1))
            OR (N'Allusers' = [table1].[VISIBLE_TO])
            OR ([table1].[OWNER_USER_ID] = @d)
            OR (
                EXISTS (
                    SELECT 1 AS [C]
                    FROM [dbo].[TeamMembers] AS [table2]
                    WHERE ([table1].[INS_ID] = [table2].[INS_ID])
                        AND ([table1].[VISIBLE_TEAM_ID] = [table2].[TEAM_ID])
                        AND ([table2].[INS_ID] = [table1].[INS_ID])
                        AND ([table2].[MEMBER_USER_ID] = @d)
                        AND ([table2].[TEAM_ID] = [table1].[VISIBLE_TEAM_ID])
                    )
                )
            )
    ) AS [XYZ];
```

Comment: Better if you upload the actual plan
https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/

Comment: This is likely an artifact of you using local variables (declaring at the top and running the query). What happens when you use a RECOMPILE hint?

Answer (score 1):

There are some *redundant JOINs between the 2 tables*, and using too many `OR` conditions with *nested queries* sometimes overwhelms the SQL Query Optimiser.

After cleaning up and organising the code, I've come up with the following (hopefully equivalent) alternative:

```
DECLARE @a INT
    ,@b BIT
    ,@c INT
    ,@d INT
    ,@e INT;

SELECT SUM(CNT) AS [C]
FROM (
    SELECT COUNT(1) AS [CNT]
    FROM [dbo].[EmailTable]
    WHERE 1 = 1
        AND [ACTIVE] = 1
        AND [INS_ID] = @a
        AND [QUEUED_TO_SEND] = @b
        AND [OWNER_USER_ID] <> @c
        AND (
            [OWNER_USER_ID] IN (- 1)
            OR N'Allusers' = [VISIBLE_TO]
            OR [OWNER_USER_ID] = @d
            )

    UNION ALL

    SELECT COUNT(1) AS [CNT]
    FROM [dbo].[EmailTable] AS [table1]
    WHERE 1 = 1
        AND [table1].[ACTIVE] = 1
        AND [table1].[INS_ID] = @a
        AND [table1].[QUEUED_TO_SEND] = @b
        AND [table1].[OWNER_USER_ID] <> @c
        AND EXISTS (
            SELECT 1 AS [C]
            FROM [dbo].[TeamMembers] AS [table2]
            WHERE [table2].[INS_ID] = [table1].[INS_ID]
                AND [table2].[TEAM_ID] = [table1].[VISIBLE_TEAM_ID]
                AND [table2].[MEMBER_USER_ID] = @d
            )
    ) XYZ
OPTION(RECOMPILE);
```

Let us know how it works and maybe **post the Actual Execution Plan**, as some commenters requested.